# How can I increase The Whispered World's resolution?

Tags: the-whispered-world

The default resolution for The Whispered World is 1024x768. I can't seem to find any way to increase this. I run dual monitors, so having it at such a small resolution makes my secondary monitor nearly useless.

I navigated to `\Steam\steamapps\common\whispered world\` and opened the `config.ini` file, however there are no options regarding the resolution in this file, the contents of which are below:

```
FILE = data.vis
FULLSCREEN = no

MusicVolume = 90
SoundVolume = 95
SpeechVolume = 100
```

There's an executable `TWWOptions.exe`, however, this only allows me to choose whether I want it to run in Windowed or Fullscreen mode. Is it hidden in another file somewhere or is there simply no way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe The Whispered World does not use 3D graphics - they seem to be fully hand-drawn 2D. In such case it might be there is no option for changing the resolution, as this would require graphics fitting bigger or smaller screen.